# Center the content and float inside

Tags: css, css-float

I am confused about float: I have a div menu with 2 items inside. I center it with margin 0 auto. If I put blue and red in float is not centered anymore and gets out of content. I do not understand why?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/A4FHd/

CSS:

```
#content{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    background:yellow;
}

#text{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:justify;
}

#menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:0;
    background:grey;
}

#blue{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    z-index:0;
    background:blue;
}
#red{
    float:left;
    width:50px; height:50px;
    z-index:0;
    background:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">

    <div id="text"> 
    some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
    </div>

    <div id="menu"> 
        <div id="red"> </div>
        <div id="blue"> </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper `div`
and if you want the menu to be centered as well - you must specify the width of its content:
http://jsfiddle.net/A4FHd/5/

You need to specify a width because the floated elements are out of flow and do not contribute to computing the width of the parent element (containing block).

Comment: do you mean I need to specify the width of #menu?, why is it necessary?

Comment: `overflow: auto` also works, same idea, start a new formatting context.

Comment: @Nrc if you don't specify its width - it will fill the whole available width by default (this is how `display: block` behaves) - if you want to avoid specifying the width - don't use `float` on your menu items but change their `display` to `inline-block` (which doesn`t exist on IE<8)